# MonoMac create context in background thread

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, monomac

This is the error I am getting:

MonoMac.AppKit.AppKitThreadAccessException: AppKit Consistency error: you are calling a method that can only be invoked from the UI thread.

I want to lay out my program as shown [in the apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_threading/opengl_threading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001987-CH409-SW4) figure 14-1.

[image]

[The following stack-overflow question seems to suggest this can be achieved in cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282287/threaded-rendering-with-nsopenglview)

The documentation seems to state that multiple gl context are perfectly plausible, so I'm guessing that at least some of these must exist outside of the main UI thread.

I am guessing that [this could well be the problem](http://tirania.org/monomac/archive/2012/Sep-10.html). However I want to make sure that a nsglcontext in a separate thread is not implicitly dangerous and that one just has to follow the usual precautions one does when working with multi-threaded opengl programs.

Any help would save my table from being head-butted any more and thus would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the blog post link in the question you can use the following to turn of cross thread ui checks.

```
//
// Disable UIKit thread checks for a couple of methods
//
var previous = UIApplication.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls;
UIApplication.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCall = false;

// Perform some UIKit calls here
foo.Bar = 1;

// Restore
UIApplication.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = previous;
```

Do note though if you are doing the wrong thing this would also hide the problem, so use this sparingly.